# Evaluate arguments in a curried function left to right

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have an *inner* pattern

```
f[g, n_] := inner
```

and I want to define an *outer* curried pattern

```
f[h, m_][f[g, n_]] := ...
```

which has unrelated behaviour to `f[g,n]` and so should receive expression `f[g,n]` rather than `inner`. Alas, `f[h,m][f[g,n]]` is undesiredly first evaluated as `f[h,m][inner]`. How can I prevent Mathematica from evaluating the inner `f[g,n]` whilst still recognising a pattern for `f[h,m_][..]` without having to explicitly insert `Hold` into the outermost expression?

Of course `SetAttribute[f, HoldAll]` doesn't work, and I can't exactly set an attribute for the experssion `f[h]`.

**My motivation:** I'm creating inner "functions" with subscript "arguments", and I want to define an outer "functional" which also has subscript "arguments" which should start evaluating before the passed inner functions are evaluated.

E.g.

```
Subscript[g1, n_] := bad[n]
Subscript[g2, n_] := bad[n] 
...

Subscript[h, m_][ Subscript[g_,n_] ] := good[g,m,n]
```

I want the behaviourwhere $g1_n$ gives `bad[n]`, but $h_m[g1_n]$ gives `good[g1,m,n]`. The above code instead gives $h_m[bad[n]]$.

I notice that the last line of the above code doesn't affect the DownValues of Subscript:

```
DownValues[Subscript]

    {HoldPattern[Subscript[g1, n_]] :> bad[n], 
    HoldPattern[Subscript[g2, n_]] :> bad[n]}
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: @kglr Actually the "inner" arguments aren't declared verbatim (see my motivation)

Comment: @kglr Pardon the over-simplicity in the original statement of my problem - please see 'my motivation'

Comment: Some of us here think that using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables) should be avoided. `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: I agree, but I'm still looking to do it :) I can use `/:` to attach an `OwnValues` to `x` if that was really a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run into problems like this, I workaround it by using `ReplaceAll` like so:

```
rules = {
  f[g, n_] :> inner,
  f[h, m_][f[g, n_]] :> outer
};

f[h, m][f[g, n]] //. rules

(* outer *)
```

That's because while the [standard evaluation procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html) looks at elements before moving up, `ReplaceAll` works by first trying to match the [whole expression before going deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836972/1949370).

Comment: Works fantastic. I'll hopelessly wait a little longer for I accept this answer :)